# Hide Detail Band in jasper report

Tags: jasper-reports

Data that we get from data source is not shown in detail band. But make some processing for each of records and processing result is shown in Group footer.

So I **cannot remove** detail band, as it is the only place for processing individual record. But I want to hide it, making invisible.

If I use `printWhenExpression`, it causes not only hiding the detail band but also no processing is done for records.

What I want is **just hide**(making invisible and do not make any blank) but **processing is done for each iteration**. If possible, may I know how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Remove all elements (static text, text field and so on) from detail band and set height = 0 px at detail band property

Answer (score 0):

You can either set its height to 0 px in the properties section on the right side

OR

You can Right click > delete band. (The band can later be added back if needed).